# Rpart regression tree using aggregate data instead of record level data – The results are not the same

Tags: r, cart, aggregation, rpart

I have a large dataset (over 6 million records) and I have aggregated the dataset (`dplyer` package) and tested `rpart()` on the two datasets. However the results of the two trees are not the same.  I wanted to use aggregated data to speed up the calculations – Is this approach incorrect?

**Tree: Data no aggregated - no weights**

```
rpart.fraud <- rpart(PERCENTAGE_FRAUD ~ VERTICALNAME + ROUNDED_AMOUNT_TRANSACTIONS_EUR,
                     data = fraud_data)
```

**The tree has 1 node unless I used  `control = rpart.control(cp=0.001)` and then I have some nodes: 14 nodes**

```
fraud_data_sum <- select(fraud_data,VERTICALNAME,ROUNDED_AMOUNT_TRANSACTIONS_EUR,NUMBER_TRXS_PAID, NUMBER_TRXS_PAID_CBFRAUD) %>%
            group_by(VERTICALNAME,ROUNDED_AMOUNT_TRANSACTIONS_EUR) %>%
            summarise(NUMBER_TRXS_PAID=sum(NUMBER_TRXS_PAID),
                      NUMBER_TRXS_PAID_CBFRAUD = sum(NUMBER_TRXS_PAID_CBFRAUD),
                      PERCENTAGE_FRAUD = sum(NUMBER_TRXS_PAID_CBFRAUD)/sum(NUMBER_TRXS_PAID))
```

**Tree: Data aggregated - using `weights` argument**

```
rpart.fraud <- rpart(PERCENTAGE_FRAUD ~ VERTICALNAME + ROUNDED_AMOUNT_TRANSACTIONS_EUR,
                     data = fraud_data_sum, weights = NUMBER_TRXS_PAID)
```

**the tree (using aggregate data and weights) has 30 nodes (using the default control cp).**

Answer (score 2):

I did try out both above mentioned methods once in the past. Both methods are correct. However, you will get different trees because the minsplit and minbucket criteria doesn't take weights of the records into consideration. minsplit and minbucket is checked on the number of records.

Hope that answers your question.